# Prove that if $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=a>0 $ then $a_n>0$ eventually.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

I know that the solution is really simple but still i can't find it. Can you give me a hint first and the solution after?

Comment: Hint: use the definition of a limit.

Comment: "Then $a_n>0$ __________"  You are missing a very important qualification here.  It is not true that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n = a>0$ that $a_n>0$ for all $n$.  Take for trivial counterexample the sequence $(-1,1,1,1,1,1\dots)$, the first term is negative despite the sequence converging to $1$.

Comment: Hint. Use the definition of limit with $\epsilon = a/2$. And you want $a_n > 0$ eventually.

Comment: It should read "*If $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=a>0$ then there exists some $N$ for which $a_n>0$ for all $n>N$*"

Comment: The correct statement is that $a_n > 0$ for all except finitely many $n$.

Answer (score 1):

If $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=a>0 $ then $$\forall \epsilon>0\quad \exists M\quad \forall n>M \quad |a_n-a|<\epsilon$$ take $\epsilon={a}$ therefore $$\exists M\quad \forall n>M \quad |a_n-a|<\epsilon=a\to -a<a_n-a<a\to \quad 0<a_n<2a$$
but this doesn't mean at all that all the terms of $a_n$ are positive (take $a_n=(1+\frac{1}{n})^n-2.5$)

Comment: Yeah, it's my mistake. We want $a_n>0$ eventually.